# Увеличение размера динамического массива, реализуемого на shared_ptr

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы, shared-ptr

Есть метод push_back для динамического массива.

```
void TVector::push_back(const Square& value) {
    if(_size == 0){
        auto _array = std::make_shared<std::array<Square, 1>>();
        (*_array)[0] = value;
        _size++;
    }
    else{
        auto _array = std::make_shared<std::array<Square, _size>>();
        (*_array)[_size] = value;
        _size++;
    }
}
```

Она работает когда размер нулевой, то есть динамический массив еще пустой, но как только размер становится единица и больше, не совсем понятно как выделять дополнительную память. На

```
auto _array = std::make_shared<std::array<Square, _size>>();
```

жалуется IDE таким образом `Non-type template argument is not a constant expression`.
Подскажите, есть ли какой-то способ похожий на realloc по смыслу для умного указателя shared_ptr, чтобы можно было реализовать данный метод.

Comment: размер `std::array` должен быть константой известной при сборке. Тут еще проблема в том, что значение, присвоенное `_array` сразу теряется при выходе из области видимости. Если нужен массив с размером, задаваемом во время исполнения, то используйте `::std::vector`.

Comment: @user7860670, а если вообще нельзя использовать vector по заданию? Так как задача реализовать свой контейнер динамический массив.

Comment: Ну тогда использовать `shared_ptr<type[]>`  или скорее даже `unique_ptr<type[]>`, так сложно представить, что контейнер будет разделять владение буфером с чем-то еще.

Comment: @user7860670, можете объяснить, пожалуйста, что надо в if и else писать? Просто мне не понятен сам принцип, каким способом мы расширяем область занимаемой памяти для умных указателей, так как для обычных указателей я понимаю, что сначала мы пишем malloc, потом realloc.

Comment: Область никак не расширяется, надо выделять новый буфер, а затем копировать все объекты из старого буфер в новый. Семантики `realloc` при выделении памяти через `new` вообще нет.

Comment: @user7860670, если я использую `std::shared_ptr<Square[]> _array(new Square[_size]);`, то как мне обращаться к элементам массива? оператор [] в данном случае не работает, и я не могу совершить присваивание `_array[0] = value;`

Comment: "не работает" не является описанием проблемы. оператор [] как раз должен именно таким образом работать. ¿Может оно собирается без C++17?

Comment: Раз уж размер не константа времени выполнения — может, использовать `vector` и не мучиться?

Comment: @Harry задание заключается реализовать свой контейнер, поэтому приходится не использовать vector(

Comment: Ну, а если свой контейнер — то не проще через обычные массивы? Да и `shared_ptr` — зачем? Что это дает?

Answer (score 0):

Всё сложно, тут одна из основных проблем темплейтов в C++.

Дело в том, что при компиле

```
std::array<Square, 1>
std::array<Square, 2>
std::array<Square, 3>
```

Компилятор генерит разный код для каждого из 3 типов. Для C++ это 3 совершенно различных типа.
И такое не скомпилится:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, 4242>> p=std::make_shared<std::array<int, 42>>();
```

Но раз уж пошли таким путём, то если очень постараться, то можно запилить такое.

Для начала понадобится массив типов. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015710/for-loop-over-template-arguments-types

Массив соответственно из:

```
std::array<Square, 1>
std::array<Square, 2>
std::array<Square, 4>
std::array<Square, 8>
```

Можно и не кратные 2 если хочется.

Далее так как это всё разные типы, то нельзя просто так:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, 4242>> p=std::make_shared<std::array<int, 42>>();
```

Нам нужен либо variant, либо void

```
std::shared_ptr<std::variant<all_types array 1 2 4 8>>
std::shared_ptr<void>
```

Далее что-то типо такого:

```
std::variant<all_types array 1 2 4 8> make_shared_of(int size){
    std::optional<std::variant<all_types array 1 2 4 8>> res;
    for_<all_types array 1 2 4 8>([&]<typename T>(T* type_dummy){
        if(!res && T().size() >= size)
            res = T();
    });
    return *res;
}

void TVector::resize(int size) {
    auto _array = make_shared_of(size);
    _size = size;
    // copy array data...
}

void TVector::push_back(const Square& value) {
    resize(_size + 1);
    std::visit([&](auto&& arg){arg[_size - 1] = value;}, array);
}
```

О том какого размер будет .exe, и как быстро компилиться, и работать я не буду упоминать.